# hibernate populate database on first run

Tags: hibernate, auto-populate

It is possible to make Hibernate insert Java Objects only one first run of the application?

I don't want to load an inser.sql file, i think that is possible to instantiate all my java objects in a specific java file and only on the first run hibernate populate de DB with that objects.
How to do it?

Comment: are you using spring along with hibernate or any other framework?

Comment: have a look to answer provided below solution with hibernate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can achieve this by providing `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` configuration parameter of hibernate. with this configuration you can specify SQL files to be imported after creation of schema. refer to hibernate [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html) for more information.